# Why does dictionary take less time than set in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, hashtable

Both dictionary and sets are implemented as hash tables in Python and have an insertion time and lookup time of O(1). I am writing a program to count if the string consists of all unique characters and I am using a set to keep a track of all the characters seen so far. What I observe is if I use a dictionary instead of a set the overall run time of the program is a little faster. Can anyone please explain me the reason for this?

Code Using a dictionary:

```
def TestUniqueCharacters(characters):
    chars = {}
    for character in characters:
        if character not in chars:
            chars[character] = 1
        else:
            return False
    return True

for i in range(30000000):
    TestUniqueCharacters("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890-=[];',.!@#$%^&*()")
```

Code using a set

```
def TestUniqueCharacters(characters):
    chars = set()
    for character in characters:
        if character not in chars:
            chars.add(character)
        else:
            return False
    return True

for i in range(30000000):
    TestUniqueCharacters("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890-=[];',.!@#$%^&*()")
```

Execution time with dictionary

[image: Execution time with dictionary]

Execution time with set

[image: Execution time with set]

Comment: Have you defined an error margin before doing your comparison? Was it larger than the difference in the results?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not inclined to spend much time on this, because the implementations of dicts and sets vary across Python releases.  Chasing down version-dependent minor mysteries just isn't much fun ;-)

So I'll just *suggest* changing:

```
chars = set()
for character in characters:
    if character not in chars:
        chars.add(character)
```

to:

```
chars = set()
charsadd = chars.add   # new line here
for character in characters:
    if character not in chars:
        charsadd(character)  # this line is different - no method lookup now
```

to see what happens under whichever version of Python you happen to be using.

In the original `chars.add(...)`, each time through the loop the method with string name `"add"` has to be looked up on the `chars` object, and a bound method object created, which is then called with argument `character`.  While not a major expense, this isn't free.  In the suggested rewrite, the `add` method is looked up only once, outside the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your suggestion. It did bring down the execution time considerably. The average time of execution for sets in now down to 1min 45sec from approximately 2 min 20sec I was getting earlier.